# How to solve: $0 = -\sin \space 3x \cdot3, \left({\pi\over 12}, {7\pi \over12}\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, roots

While working on some Rolle's Theorem problems I came to:

$$f(x) = \cos 3x$$

This is both continuous on the given interval (and everywhere really) $[{\pi\over 12}, {7\pi \over12}]$ and differentiable $({\pi\over 12}, {7\pi \over12})$. Additionally, $f({7\pi \over12}) = f({\pi\over 12})$. So all three hypotheses check out.

So now I need to find the c-values on the open interval. So I take the derivative and solve for zero:

$$0 = -\sin 3x \cdot3$$

However, my trig is very rusty. How do I solve this? I figured out the answer as ${4\pi\over 12}$ by determining what I would need to get $sin\space \pi$ (i.e. $\pi= 3\cdot({\pi\over12})$). Is this how you solve this type of trig problem, or is there a better, more formal, robust, standard way?

Comment: What do you mean "c-values on the open interval"?

Comment: I think he means the values $c$ for which $f'(c) = 0$ in the interval $[\frac{\pi}{12},\frac{7\pi}{12}]$, from Roll's Theorem.

Comment: @Hidde, correct, except in my book it says that the number(s) c would be on the open interval, not closed.

Comment: @Matt You're very right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can obviously divide through by $-3$ to get the equation $\sin(3x)=0$.
From here it's easy: $\sin(y)=0$ if and only if $y=k\pi$ for some integer $k$. So if we let $y=3x\ldots$
Once we have all the solutions like so, it becomes obvious that the only solution in your chosen interval is $x=4\pi/12$

Comment: So I essentially solved it correctly it appears. Thanks for the validation. It's just been so long with trig that I worry I'm forgetting something.